# Three Musketeers - the diamond studs

Tags: french-language, historical-context, alexandre-dumas-pere, the-three-musketeers

The plot of the first part of *The Three Musketeers* revolves around 12 diamond studs that Queen Anne d'Autriche gives to the Duke of Buckingham.

What exactly were those studs? I mean, what was this object of jewellery? How were they to be worn?

Comment: Looking at *Les Trois Mousquetaires* in French, as well as a French dictionary, each stud was [two buttons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button#Styles_of_attachment) (only one of which would have been visible) connected by a short ribbon. It would have been attached at a buttonhole, and used either to keep an article of clothing (in this case a  *pourpoint*, or doublet) closed, or purely for decoration.  Think of a fancy tuxedo shirt today. Unless somebody who speaks French better than I do gets to it first, I'll write a real answer when I have time.

Comment: @PeterShor "Sur son épaule gauche étincelaient les ferrets soutenus par un noeud de même couleur que les plumes et la jupe" is the relevant quote. In modern French, as far as I know, a "ferret" is the tip of the shoelace, with that hardened thing on it that makes it easier to pull the shoelace through the eyelets. Only, that doesn't make sense in context, leaving me even more confused.

Comment: The Larousse dictionary also has for *ferret*, *"Petit bout (en métal, en pierre précieuse, etc.) d'une aiguillette."* And an *aiguillette* is un *"Cordon, ganse ou tresse, ferré aux deux bouts, ayant, jusqu'au règne de Louis XIV, servi à fermer ou à garnir les vêtements."* I'm guessing from context, and from the translation to *stud*, that they were used both to close and to decorate buttonholes.

Comment: I'm wrong. We have, later in *Les Trois Mousquetaires*, *"«Tenez, lui dit-il en tirant du coffre un gros noeud de ruban bleu tout étincelant de diamants; tenez, voici ces précieux ferrets avec lesquels j'avais fait le serment d'être enterré.»"* So we have a blue ribbon knot meant to be pinned on a shoulder, and decorated with diamonds (the *ferrets*, which must be attached to the ends of the ribbons like shoelace ends). So the translation to *studs* seems wrong. Also English Wikipedia has an entry for [aiguillette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiguillette). Unfortunately, Wikipédia doesn't.

Comment: @PeterShor Do you want to make that into an answer, with the relevant pictures from Wikipedia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The French word that was translated to *stud* was *ferret*. I don't actually see any justification for translating *ferret* here as *stud*, as I will explain later.

To explain how the diamonds were worn first, these twelve diamond *ferrets* were part of a decoration meant to be worn on a shoulder. It was made of six blue ribbons woven or knotted together. The twelve *ferrets* were ornamental tips attached to the ends of the ribbons.

The rest of the answer contains the justification for this statement. To see what *ferret* means, let us look at the relevant definition from the [*Larousse dictionnaire de français.*](https://larousse.fr/) This is

> Petit bout (en métal, en pierre précieuse, etc.) d'une aiguillette.
> Small tip (of metal, gemstone, etc.) of an aiguillette.

So what is an *aiguillette*? The English translation is aiguillette, but this won't help modern readers because the word has largely fallen out of use in both English and French (because aiguillettes aren't used much anymore). *Larousse* says that an *aiguillette* is

> Cordon, ganse ou tresse, ferré aux deux bouts, ayant, jusqu'au règne de Louis XIV, servi à fermer ou à garnir les vêtements.
> Cord or braid, tipped with metal at both ends, that until the reign of Louis XIV served to fasten or decorate clothing.

So an *aguillette* was a short length of cord or braid, tipped at both ends, often with precious metal or gemstones, that was used to fasten clothing closed, or which was worn purely for decoration.

One can see pictures of them in [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiguillette). This says

> Portraits of the 16th and 17th centuries show that aiglets or metal tips could be functional or purely decorative, though many were used to "close" seams and slashes that are not always apparent on dark garments in portraits. They were made in matched sets, might be of silver, silver-gilt, or gold, and were worn in masses.

Here is a 1562 picture of Lord High Admiral Clinton wearing a doublet fastened by aiguillettes, from Wikipedia.

[image: Lord High Admiral Clinton in an arming doublet of 1562]

So were the diamonds on aiguillettes? If they were, *stud* might be a reasonable translation of *ferret*, because a stud is a piece of jewelry that you use to fasten two buttonholes together, and similarly an aiguillette is a piece of jewelry you use to fasten your clothing.

However, in this case, the *ferrets* were not on aiguillettes, although they were indeed on the ends of ribbons.

The first time we see the *ferrets* being worn is:

> elle [la reine] avait un chapeau de feutre avec des plumes bleues, un surtout en velours gris perle rattaché avec des agrafes de diamants, et une jupe de satin bleu toute brodée d'argent. Sur son épaule gauche étincelaient les ferrets soutenus par un noeud de même couleur que les plumes et la jupe.
>
> She [The Queen] wore a felt hat with blue feathers, a surcoat of gray-pearl velvet, fastened with diamond clasps, and a skirt of blue satin, embroidered with silver. On her left shoulder sparkled the diamond *ferrets*, on a knot of the same color as the plumes and the skirt.

A later description of
the diamonds in *Les Trois Mousquetaires* follows:

> Tenez, lui dit-il en tirant du coffre un gros noeud de ruban bleu tout étincelant de diamants; tenez, voici ces précieux ferrets ...
> “Here,” said he, drawing from the casket a large knot of blue ribbon all glittering with diamonds, “here are the precious *ferrets* ...

Note that the French word *noeud* is broader than the English word *knot*; a bow would also be called a *noeud*.

So the *ferrets* are in a large decoration made of blue ribbon. We also find that this was meant to be worn on a shoulder. This decoration must then be made of six blue ribbons knotted or woven together somehow, and the diamonds are on pieces of jewelry which are affixed to the twelve ends of these six ribbons.

Note: the English translations above are my modifications of the translations of *The Three Musketeers* on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1257/1257-h/1257-h.htm).

NOTE: the first passage I quote above from *Les Trois Mousquetaires* seems to have been changed between the serialization where it first appears, and the 1850 novel edition of *Les Trois Mousquetaires* published in Paris. The language in the novel seems compatible with the idea that the *ferrets* are on *aguillettes*. See the other answer.

Comment: The English word "aglet" derived from "aiguillette" is still in use for those bits on the ends of shoelaces.

Answer (score 6):

In the original French version of the novel, what d'Artagnan has to recover from London are ***[ferrets](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferret_(v%C3%AAtement))*** (engl. [aglets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglet)). An aglet is a small sheath that allows to easily slide a lace or ribbon through an eyelet hole. During the seventeenth century, these had became purely decorative and could be made from fragile minerals such as rock crystal or be adorned with diamonds.

An exhibition about *[Les Mousquetaires](https://www.musee-armee.fr/au-programme/expositions/detail/mousquetaires.html)* at the [Musée de l'Armée](https://www.musee-armee.fr/) in 2014 displayed some historic objects related to the novel by Alexandre Dumas. Among them were *ferrets* owned by the Marquise Arconati-Visconti from circa 1895-1897. They are no. 48 in the lower half of this image from the exhibition catalogue:

[image]

How these *ferrets* were worn can be seen in the following portrait of Anne of Austria, where they are attached to red ribbons:

[image]

Comment: From The Three Musketeers (Gutenberg version): *"It is true that the habit of a huntress became her [the queen] admirably. She wore a beaver hat with blue feathers, a surtout of gray-pearl velvet, fastened with diamond clasps, and a petticoat of blue satin, embroidered with silver. On her left shoulder sparkled the diamond studs, on a bow of the same color as the plumes and the petticoat."* So these *ferrets* were not attached to *aiguillettes* (something I thought, too, when I was first researching my answer), but to a knot or bow of blue ribbon, worn on a shoulder.

Comment: @PeterShor That translation appears to be a mistranslation. The phrases "fastened with diamond clasps" and "on a bow of the same color as the plumes and the petticoat" are missing from the French original. They have apparently been added by the translator. The original reads: *"Il est vrai que sa toilette de chasseresse lui allait à merveille ; elle avait un chapeau de feutre avec des plumes bleues, un surtout de velours gris perle et une jupe de satin bleu toute brodée d’argent. À ce surtout étincelaient les ferrets de diamants."*

Comment: [contd.] That is, the last sentence states that the ferrets "sparkle on the surcoat". There is no mention that they are on the shoulder, nor that they are attached to a bow. A surcoat or great coat *(surtout)* is what Anne of Austria is wearing in the portrait shown in my answer.

Comment: Project Gutenberg has *"elle avait un chapeau de feutre avec des plumes bleues, un surtout en velours gris perle rattaché avec des agrafes de diamants, et une jupe de satin bleu toute brodée d'argent. Sur son épaule gauche étincelaient les ferrets soutenus par un noeud de même couleur que les plumes et la jupe."* This is the same as Google books has for the 1846 serialization in the *Semaine Littéraire du Courrier des États-Unis*. But Google books shows that the 1850 novel, published in Paris, has your version. There are two French originals. Maybe Dumas changed his mind.

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting. I stand corrected. Nevertheless a *noeud* is simply a ribbon tied into a bow as seen in the portrait of Anne of Austria.

Comment: A simple ribbon tied in a bow is not going to have twelve *ferrets* on it. It could be a very complicated bow. I was imagining some kind of complicated épaulette-like braided knot, but I am happy to admit that that was a wild guess.